# creating and persisting entities from servlets

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, persistence, entity, ejb-3.1

I am trying to create and persist entity in servlet and when called

`public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }`

from servlet, that is generated method in AbstractFacade for all EJBs I get EJBException. Now, I am thinking to create and persist entity in stateless EJB using this method and call it from the servlet

`public boolean createUser(JavaBean jb){}`.

Is this good idea? What is the best way to create and persist entity, i.e. create user account?

Thanks for any help.

Here is the problem. 
I want to create records in two tables in database, member_details and address. They have one to one relationship. The relationship is not enforced by foreign key in database yet.  Both tables have corresponding entity classes and entity class Address has Embeddable class AddressPK representing its composite primary key. One to one relationship is only enforced in entities by `@ JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID")` in Address and by `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "memberId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` in MemberDetails`. Now, I get data from JSP form and JavaBean set in another JSP. Servlet creates entities and calls injected EJB to persist them as follows:

```
        //get MemberBean from session object
    MemberBean member = (MemberBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    //create relevant entities and set attributes of entity classes
    MemberDetails aMember = new MemberDetails("M3", firstName, middleName, lastName, dob, phoneNo,
            member.getEmail(), gender, industryPosition, "Basic", musicInterests);
    AddressPK addressId = new AddressPK(houseNo, postCode);
    Address anAddress = new Address(addressId, street, county, town, country, aMember);
    aMember.setAddress(anAddress);


    if (memberDetails.find(aMember.getMemberId()) == null) {
        //address.create(anAddress);

        memberDetails.create(aMember);

    }
    else
    { System.out.println("User M3 Exists");}

    //tests
    memberDetails.displayMembers();

    RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/accounttype.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
```

I created ordinary Java app client and inserted these details using explicit transaction and it worked. It also works when comment out the Address and keep only MemberDetails.

Here is exception I get when trying to insert MemberDetails and Address together.

WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB MemberDetailsFacade, method: public void beans.MemberDetailsFacade.create(entities.MemberDetails)
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy233.create(Unknown Source)
    at servlets.NewAccountFormHandler.doPost(NewAccountFormHandler.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: entities.MemberDetails.
    ...

Comment: What are you asking exactly? If you want to understand why you get an EJBException, you should show us the stack trace of the exception and the relevant code.

Comment: There is certainly no need to define an EJB that only persists entities. Show us more details about the error

Comment: Are you declaring entities as EJB ?

Comment: I added complete description above including the exception. I do not declare entities as EJB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but using a stateless EJB that encapsulates the entitymanager is indeed a best practice.

Such an EJB can be injected into a Servlet without having to worry about thread-safety issues.

If you use an entity manager directly in a Servlet you have to be aware of such issues (an entity manager is not thread-safe and there's only 1 Servlet instance for all requests. You would also have to manually manage transactions.

With a simple and lightweight EJB bean all that complexity just goes away.

Comment: Yes, I have an entity manager encapsulated in EJB and I call `create()` method which is method in abstract class implemented be the EJB from servlet on injected EJB.